# Get number from Oracle version

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I'm interested how I can get only the number from the Oracle version?

```
select * from v$version where banner like 'Oracle%';

BANNER                                                                         
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Oracle Database 11g Express Edition Release 11.2.0.2.0 - 64bit Production  


BANNER
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    CON_ID
----------
Oracle Database 12c Enterprise Edition Release 12.1.0.2.0 - 64bit Production    
         0
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are many ways.

You could check `VERSION` in **V$INSTANCE** view:

```
SQL> SELECT version FROM V$INSTANCE;

VERSION
-----------------
12.1.0.1.0
```

You could check `VERSION` in **PRODUCT_COMPONENT_VERSION** view:

```
SQL> SELECT VERSION
  2  FROM PRODUCT_COMPONENT_VERSION
  3  WHERE product LIKE '%Oracle Database%';

VERSION
--------------------------------------------
12.1.0.1.0
```

You could use **DBMS_DB_VERSION** package:

```
SQL> set serveroutput on
SQL> BEGIN
  2    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(DBMS_DB_VERSION.VERSION || '.' || DBMS_DB_VERSION.RELEASE);
  3  END;
  4  /
12.1

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

---

**UPDATE** To get both the product and version as separate columns, you could do:

```
SQL> SELECT product AS edition,
  2         version
  3  FROM PRODUCT_COMPONENT_VERSION
  4  WHERE product LIKE '%Oracle Database%';

EDITION                                  VERSION
---------------------------------------- ----------
Oracle Database 12c Enterprise Edition   12.1.0.1.0
```

Comment: I get SELECT version FROM V$INSTANCE
Error at Command Line : 7 Column : 21
Error report -
SQL Error: ORA-00942: table or view does not exist
00942. 00000 -  "table or view does not exist"
*Cause:    
*Action:

Comment: @PeterPenzov It means the user you have logged in as doesn't have the privilege to access the `v$instance` view. Try with SYS or SYSTEM user.

Comment: How I can grant this privilege?

Comment: @PeterPenzov Login using `SYS AS SYSDBA` and do `GRANT SELECT ON V$INSTANCE TO user`. Usually you would create required roles and grant the privileges to the role and then give that role to a user.

Comment: @PeterPenzov Please mark it as answered, would help others too!

Comment: One last question is there a way to display only the edition of the database?

Comment: @PeterPenzov Just do `SELECT product AS edition FROM PRODUCT_COMPONENT_VERSION WHERE product LIKE '%Oracle Database%';`

Comment: Thanks. Can I also get the number version from this table?

Comment: Can I also get the number version from this table?

Comment: @PeterPenzov Updated my answer, check it out.

Answer (score 2):

Just for fun, using the query you presented:

```
select 
   banner, 
   regexp_substr(banner,'[0-9]*\.[0-9]*\.[0-9]*\.[0-9]*') version,
   substr(banner,1, instr(banner,'Release')-2) edition
from v$version 
where banner like 'Oracle%';
```

PS: I don't use the 5th part of the version in common conversations. And many others do the same.

Comment: Do you know how I can display only the edition of the database?

Comment: My query extracts that. You just play with substr and instr.

Comment: It is nice that you accepted my answer, but I would use `select * from PRODUCT_COMPONENT_VERSION;` as Lalit mentioned, instead of these string extracts:)

Comment: Ok, but I get 4 rows as a query result. How I can get  only the second row?

Comment: I don't know how that view looks like in 12c.